# Radiobutton is not getting selected while setting values in form

Tags: javascript, extjs, radio-button, radio-group

I have some ExtJS forms containing radiogroups.

And each of these radioGroups have 2 radios having `inputValue`s as `true` and `false`.

But when I set form values using `form.setValues(values)`, if radioButton value I want to set is `false`, respective radio is not getting selected. This works in case my value is `true`.

Here is link for [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y0tpuoc6/4/)

This works if you change `booleanRadio: true`.

My Code:

```
Ext.define('myView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'myView',
    id: 'myViewContainer',
    layout: 'vbox',
    width: '100%',
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        var allItems = [];
        allItems.push(me.getMyForm());
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: allItems
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    getMyForm: function() {
        var me = this;
        var currentForm = {
            xtype: 'form',
            cls: 'y-form',
            id: 'myForm',
            trackResetOnLoad: true,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'radiogroup',
                    fieldLabel: 'is Sponsored',
                    labelSeparator: '',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'radiofield',
                            name: 'isSponsored',
                            boxLabel: 'Yes',
                            inputValue: true
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'radiofield',
                            name: 'isSponsored',
                            boxLabel: 'No',
                            inputValue: false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };

        return currentForm;
    }
});

Ext.define('myController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'panel#myViewContainer': {
                afterrender: this.retrieveFormValues
            }
        });
    },

    retrieveFormValues: function() {
        var me = this;
        var data = {isSponsored: false};
        if (data != null && !Ext.Object.isEmpty(data)) {
            var myFormContainer = Ext.getCmp('myViewContainer');
            myFormContainer.getForm().setValues(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Added my Code.. I didn't add it earlier as it was complex. I added after simplifying it.

Comment: I have reported a very similar issue to Sencha, which is tracked as EXTJS-25448; with no workaround being available for now, except that you can convert the boolean value to strings and use these string values as radio's `inputValue`.

Comment: I think this looks like ExtJS Bug.

This is not a solution. It is only workaround.

    var values = {
                booleanRadio: result ? 1 : 0;
              };

Answer (score 0):

if you change the inputValues of radiobuttons to 0 or 1, and adjust values var accordingly, the desired radio button will be set. I have updated the fiddle.

```
items: [{
    boxLabel: 'Item 1',
    name: 'booleanRadio',
    inputValue: 1,
  }, {
    boxLabel: 'Item 2',
    name: 'booleanRadio',
    inputValue: 0,
  }],
  listeners: {
    afterrender: function(radioGroupForm) {

      var values = {
        booleanRadio: 0
      }
      Ext.getCmp('radioGroupFormPanel').getForm().setValues(values);
    }
  }
```

If you send false to radiobutton, it unchecks the radio. That's why your 'true' is working and 'false' is not.